# Run with classpath/pythonpath generated by an external tool in Intellij IDEA 13

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea

I have an external tool that generates a huge classpath/pythonpath string that I suppose to use in order to run my program.

I would like to run my program in Intellij IDEA 13 with this classpath/pythonpath. I can't find the option to do so under Run Configuration ...

Comment: You could append that to the sys.path dynamically (this is a hack though) on the very first line of your entry-point file, like app.py or __init__ inside the package you're running.

Comment: That would make it into the source code which is not what I want. My tool is fooGetLDPath configurationName. It spits out the paths I need. I simply need to inject this path into my run and allow the user to choose the configuration Name.